# Simplehtmldom innertext not working

Tags: php, html, xml, dom, simple-html-dom

So I'm using simple_html_dom:

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

I have this code:

```
$j = '
  <itemBody>
        <div>films - to watch (Simple Present)<br/>
            <textEntryInteraction responseIdentifier="RESPONSE_1"/>
        </div>
    </itemBody>';
  $dom = new simple_html_dom;
  $dom->load($j, TRUE);
  echo $dom->innertext;
```

and this returns:

```
 <itembody>
        <div>films - to watch (Simple Present)<br/>
            <textentryinteraction responseidentifier="RESPONSE_1"/>
        </div>
    </itembody>
```

Why didn't it strip out the itembody tag? (It just turned into a lower case.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't believe the `innertext` property exist in the `dom` level. try `echo $dom->plaintext;`

for `innertext` in an element level, extract an `element` from the dom object and get the innertext

```
$elm = $dom->find("div",0);
echo $elm->innertext;
```